# Xamarin App publish to Play store, error in visual studio

Tags: xamarin.android

I am publishing an app to google play store using visual studio but getting error.

[image]

here is my manifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.andriod.myapp" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="27">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="25" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="Manifest Title" android:icon="@drawable/app"></application>
</manifest>
```

this is the error I am getting

[image]

Comment: Your old project version code is 19 and target SDK 24, but now you want upgrade your project to version code 27 and target SDK 25?

Comment: Target SDK version updated, I don't want to upgrade to SDK 25 but still getting error. I have to increase version code everything I upload package, otherwise I get error.

Comment: The first picture you post is publishing successfully yesterday? But when you  publishing today it failed?

Comment: Yes, I did make some changes in target version but can't remember what changes I made and now I want to roll back but getting error. There is nothing specific I am doing in the App, so any target version will work.

Comment: any help please?